# How to bind to nested Property in MAUI

Tags: .net, xaml, data-binding, maui

I have a simple property that I have dependency-injected into my application via `AddSingleton()`, but when I bind to it from the XAML - it does not update. I tested it out with a simple string and the string property binds just fine and updates.

My ViewModel looks like this:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
public Url test;
    
public string testurl;
```

My Class:

```cs
public class Url
{
    public string Urltitle { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

My XAML:

```xml
<Entry Placeholder="Paste Link" 
    Text="{Binding Test.Url}"></Entry>

<Entry Placeholder="Paste Link" 
    Text="{Binding Testurl}"></Entry>
```

And I have also already set the `BindingContext` in my constructor like this:

```cs
BindingContext = viewModel = new ViewModel(ContentView);
```

After adding both the namespace into XAML and testing a string that is working, I am unable to bind to the nested property in my MAUI app. I would like to know what I am missing.

Comment: `Test.PIUrl` there is no property `PIUrl` in `Test`

Comment: that should work, but your UI will not refresh dynamically if `Url` is not `Observable`

Comment: Why are you passing the `ContentView` to the `ViewModel` constructor? That's not MVVM, because the ViewModel must not know about the View. Apart from that, your `Url` class is not observable and as such, your bindings cannot update, like Jason wrote.

Comment: @ewerspej I need the ContentView as the Parent needs to reload the list of URLS after navigating to adding a url successfully.  Is there another recommendation way to pass the Contentview so it can reload pages - a pattern that existed already in the project I am working on.

Comment: That requires some form of loose coupling or inversion of control. You could also use events, delegates, WeakReferenceManager, ... for that. Take your pick. At the moment, you're not doing MVVM, which is why I removed that from the title as it's misleading. It's a topic for another question, though.

Comment: Idealistically, your nested class should be observable. You should also consider making your XAML bindings TwoWay. And, lastly, if you made your nested class observable your outer ViewModel may consider subscribing to the OnPropertyChanged events from the inner/nested view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `Url` class observable and then it should work just fine:

```cs
public partial class Url : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string urltitle;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string location;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string url;
}
```

The reason why you need this is that each property must invoke the `PropertyChanged` event. It's not sufficient that the parent object is observable.