Maui MVVM: most simple pattern not working
I am working on a tiny addition of a project using the MVVM pattern.
The project is a little bit bigger, but I stripped it down to a tiny sample project to make stuff easier here.
Code
BusyViewModel.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace MauiApp6.ViewModels
{
    public partial class BusyViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool isBusy = false;
    }
}

CommandViewModel.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace MauiApp6.ViewModels
{
    public partial class CommandViewModel
    {
        private BusyViewModel busyViewModel;

        public CommandViewModel()
        {
            // Initialize BusyViewModel
            busyViewModel = new BusyViewModel();
        }

        [RelayCommand()]
        internal void Click()
        {
            // Set IsBusy to true
            busyViewModel.IsBusy = true;
        }
    }
}

MainPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp6.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiApp6.MainPage" >

    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Click Me" 
                BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:CommandViewModel}}"
                Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>

        <Label BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:BusyViewModel}}"
               Text="{Binding IsBusy}"/>

        <ActivityIndicator BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:BusyViewModel}}"
                           IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

Expected Result
After clicking on the button

The ClickCommand fires
The text of the label changes to 'true'
The ActivityIndicator starts spinning

Actual Result
After clicking the button

The ClickCommand fires
No visible change happens

Question

What is the part I am missing? I can't find the - most likely very tiny - difference to the uncountable examples out in the web.


The command busyViewModel.IsBusy = true; change the value of the CommandViewModel's busyViewModel. Did you bind the CommandViewModel's busyViewModel to the label and ActivityIndicator?

In other words,, are the CommandViewModel's busyViewModel and the BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:BusyViewModel} same instance of the BusyViewModel?

Annotate " private BusyViewModel busyViewModel;" with [ObservableProperty]. Bind to the property BindingViewModel, with {Binding BindingViewModel.IsBusy}. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76094858/how-to-bind-to-nested-property-in-maui Here in the question you can see, how the structure is setup.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT do you mean something like a CominedViewModel that holds an instance of BusyVM und CommandVM?

You have three VM instances - Command, Busy, and the instance of Busy embedded within command.  Modifications to one instance of Busy does not have any effect on the other instance of Busy

I have posted an answer to explain your code and the solution. In addition, you can read the official document about data binding to learn.

The problem is you have two BusyViewModel instances, the view model you created for the Label and the view model embedded in the CommandViewModel.
the ClickCommand changes in the one embedded in the CommandViewModel, and it does not change in the BusyViewModel of the label so no visible change will happen.
the solution is as @Liyun Zang - MSFT suggested, you should make one instance of the CommandViewModel and set the command of the button to this instance's ClickCommand property. and set the 'BindingContext' label of the Label and the ActivityIndicator to this instance's BusyViewModel property
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  // instance will be set to all the elements inside MainPage
  BindingContext= new CommandViewModel();
}

<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp6.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiApp6.MainPage" >

    <StackLayout>
       <!--because BindingContext is set for the MainPage no need set it here again and setting it again here will lead to unexpected behaviour-->
        <Button Text="Click Me"
                Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
        <!--here BindingContext will be set to CommandViewModel.BusyViewModel property-->
        <Label BindingContext="{Binding BusyViewModel}"
               Text="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
        <!--same thing-->
        <ActivityIndicator BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:BusyViewModel}}"
                           IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>



First of all, the code you used:
       <Button Text="Click Me" 
                BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:CommandViewModel}}"
                Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>

        <Label BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:BusyViewModel}}"
               Text="{Binding IsBusy}"/>

        <ActivityIndicator BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:BusyViewModel}}"
                           IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"/>

Each of the BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:xxx} in the xaml will create a new instance of the xxx class. So the bindingcontext of the ActivityIndicator and the Label are both type of BusyViewModel, but they are different instances.
The way always used to set the Binding context is declaring the instance of the viewmodel and set it in the code behind.
In addition, you don't have to set bindingcontext for every control in the page. You can just set BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:xxx} for the ContentPage. And then all the child control in the contentpage will has the bindingcontext: xxx class.
You can read the official document about Binding context inheritance.
And in your case, you can just set the MainPage's BindingContext as CommandViewModel
public partial class CommandViewModel
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private BusyViewModel busyVM;

        public CommandViewModel()
        {
            // Initialize BusyViewModel
            busyVM = new BusyViewModel();
        }

        [RelayCommand()]
        internal void Click()
        {
            // Set IsBusy to true
            busyVM.IsBusy = true;
        }
    }

And in the xaml:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp6.ViewModels"
             BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:CommandViewModel}}"
             x:Class="MauiApp6.MainPage" >

    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Click Me" 
                Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>

        <Label Text="{Binding BusyVM.IsBusy}"/>

        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding BusyVM.IsBusy}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>


You are not using your BindingContext correctly, what you need is as follows
First, you need to assign the BindingContext to your Page, once you do that you assign it as the DataType so it gets compiled and bound to your XAML the rest will do itself
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  BindingContext= new CommandViewModel();
}

In your MainPage XAML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp6.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="vm:CommandViewModel"
             x:Class="MauiApp6.MainPage" >
 <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Click Me" 
                Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>

        <Label Text="{Binding IsBusy}"/>

        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
 </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

Also, I do not get what the purpose of BusyViewModel is.

He is using nested observable objects. His outer observable object - CommandViewModel , has nested observable object field BusyViewModel, and that field has it is own field IsBusy. He knows very well how to bind to outer ViewModels, as you can read from his question - the command binding WORKS. If you are going to write an answer, respect his class organization, or guide him to one of the existing answers for nested viewmodels.

@H.A.H. My point is that a field cannot be bound, so I don't get the purpose of the BusyViewModel, either it should be a property that can be referenced, or a base class...

@FreakyAli
To my knowledge
private bool isBusy = false;

is equal to
private bool isBus = false;
public bool IsBusy
{
 get => isBusy;
 set => SetProperty(ref isBusy, value);
}

So isBusy is a field while IsBusy is a property. Am I mistaken?

@Evolyzer it is bindable, of course. But in what context? Your BindingContext is CommandViewModel. If you see this answer, Freaky is putting "x:DataType="vm:CommandViewModel". This is very important. For more than one reason. So then he can just do {Binding ClickCommand}. And the intellisense will tell him, if there is no ClickCommand in that view model. In case you do not know your BindingContext type , before the program is started - this will not apply to you. But you still need to use a nested property, to access your nested view models. I put a link to the comments. Read it.

@Evolyzer No I am talking about this private BusyViewModel busyViewModel;
